# Template 10:Get the splash screen like the course in MVA

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, template10

I just completed the course on template 10 in mva. Now I am working on this app and would like it to have the splash screen like this(of course the logo can be changed). Where should I get started to code(any tutorial)? Or if there's a sample code available.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it uses an extended splash screen. The extended splash screen in UWP is the same as it in a Windows 8.1 app. You can start with [How to extend the splash screen (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx), there is a 8.1 sample in this document, and you can also refer to the official UWP [Splash screen sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SplashScreen).

And from your picture, there is a circular `ProgressBar`, to create such a `PrgressBar`, there are several methods, for example here you can refer to [[UWP] - Circular Progress Bar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/93bd83d9-eed4-420b-841a-cfb825fdf514/uwp-circular-progress-bar?forum=wpdevelop).

**Update**:

It's quite easy, downloaded your posted project in the comment, there is a usercontrol named "RoundProgressControl", in this usercontrol, you can put a `Image` inside it like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="TheGrid" Width="28" Height="28" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent">
    <Path x:Name="ThePath" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#ff999999" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeDashCap="Flat">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="12,24" x:Name="ThePathFigure">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <ArcSegment x:Name="TheSegment" Size="12,12" IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="12,24" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Image Source="Assets/E1.png" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

I put a image source named "E1.png" in the Assets folder of the project, you can replace it with your own image. You can also modify the size of the `Image` by setting the `Width` and `Height` property.

Comment: Hey Grace thanks a lot for your reply on both sites.I have got the circular progress Bar but now how to progress it around a image like in the screenshots the image should be there and progress bar should revolve around it.Any help would be appreciated.

Got the progress Bar from here:

[link](http://www.rectorsquid.com/CircleprogressRing.zip)

Thanks Again

Comment: @Uwpbeginner, OK, I updated my answer, if you find there is no problem, please accept the answer on both sides. Thx!

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @Grace it worked.But now any idea how may i implement this into a splash screen with my app logo.Any help would be appreciated.                                                                                                                      Thanks Again

Comment: You can just replace your the image with your logo I think? Or are you asking how to implement the splash screen? If so, please refer the first link in my answer.

Comment: Hey @Grace Feng  i want this round progress control into my splash screen so it look like like the above images  but  in the extended splash screen link tutorial they show it by canvas and i want to do it by Myprogress control any idea how to implement this control in extended splash screen.If i just use it in splash.xaml then my app builds and start but then it hangs.But removing this control it runs perfectly.                               Thanks again

Comment: @Uwpbeginner, my suggestion is you can post your current code and your problems, open a new thread on SO, we can't discuss too much in the comment.

Comment: Hey @Grace Feng here is the new thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018918/get-extended-splashscreen-with-circular-progressbar-around-image)